# Read large List in Android for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, file-io, autocompletetextview

I have a file with 72000 lines and 2,6M size. In this File are all String items for a AutoCompleteTextView.
Currently i read them like this:

```
List<IcdObject> codes = new ArrayList<IcdObject>();
try {
    InputStream input = getAssets().open("icd.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] icd = line.split("|");
    codes.add(new IcdObject(icd[0], icd[1]));
    }

    input.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ArrayAdapter<IcdObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<IcdObject>(this,
    android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, codes);
AutoCompleteTextView at = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoComplete);
at.setThreshold(3);
at.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The Garbage Collector goes crazy when i start the activity. But in the end all items get loaded, after waiting around 1min.
Is there a method to load the file on demand or make it faster?

Comment: I would consider prefilling a database with the search suggestions, which should be a lot more efficient and faster than having to completely parse a large file and load all item in memory. Also, it would make a lot more sense to move the 'filtering' process off the UI thread. `ArrayAdapter` has a `getFilter()` method you can override for that purpose. If you decide to go down the database path, look at for the `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` method in `CursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) API to perform these large data set reading.
The [LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) class is used to get callback from [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)